# Restart Package Deployment from Point of Failure

Tags: ssis

I have 10 packages that I want to deploy at the same time.
When I try, some packages are not successfully deployed.

How can I restart the deployment from the point of failure?

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: If the 10 packages are on the same project you may deploy them all at once.